# chords that intersect both the positive vertical axis and the negative horizontal axis

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Let us consider the experiment of choosing at random a chord of the circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ given parametrically by $(\cos 2\pi t,\sin 2\pi t )$, $0 \leq t < 1$.  Let $\Omega$ be the unit square $[0,1)^2$. Let $\mathcal{A}$ denote the borel fied of subsets of $\Omega$ and let $P$ be the uniform distribution on $\Omega$.  Let $\Psi$ be the space of chords of the given circle and let $\mathcal{B}$ denote the Borel field of subsets of $\Psi$ with $\Psi$ being regarded as a subspace of the metric space of all compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$  (with the Hausdorff metric).

For $w=(w_1,w_2)\in \Omega$, let $X_1(w)$ denote the line segment having endpoints $(\cos 2\pi w_1,\sin 2\pi  w_1)$ and $(\cos 2\pi w_2,\sin 2\pi w_2 )$. Notice that $X_1(w)$ is a chord of the circle of interest and $X_1$ is a random set that is, a set-valued random variable.

And let $Q_1$ denote the distribution of $X_1$.

My question is How can I calculate $Q_1(C)$ where $C$ is the set of chords that intersect both the positive vertical axis and the negative horizontal axis. Could someone help me, please?

Thanks for your time and help. (some hints please!)

Comment: Why did you just delete your other, related, question?

Comment: I solve it, just I take limits and double integrals, so I thought that the question is obsolete

Comment: FYI, simple symmetry considerations show the answer $\frac1{32}$ below (which you accepted) is wrong. (And I wonder if you also "found" $\frac1{32}$ in your other question?)

Comment: Yea, and. In other post I take symmetry too ty

Comment: $\frac1{16}$ (which you seem to suggest) is wrong as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot of probability jargon here! In particular it's unclear what is meant by $Q_1$. At any rate your problem seems to be finding the set $\hat C\subset\Omega$ corresponding to segments intersecting the positive $y$-axis as well as the negative $x$-axis.

Let $e^{i\phi_1}$ and $e^{i\phi_2}$ be two points on the unit circle. Then $C$ occurs iff $$0<\phi_1<{\pi\over2}\qquad\wedge\qquad \pi<\phi_2<{3\pi\over2}\qquad\wedge\qquad \phi_2-\phi_1<\pi\ ,\tag{1}$$
or $(1)$ with $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ interchanged. The conditions $(1)$ together with their counterparts obtained by $\phi_1\leftrightarrow \phi_2$ define two small triangles in $\Omega$ of area ${1\over32}$ each (draw a figure!). It follows that the probability of $C$ comes to $2\cdot{1\over32}={1\over16}$.

Comment: sorry but why did you get $\frac{1}{32}$ ? I undertand that  $\frac{1}{16}$ is because we have two quadrants  then  $\frac{1}{32}+ \frac{1}{32} =\frac{1}{16} $ ?